# Python table classification

Tags: python, forms, distribution

I have text file(test.data), which include some values and class name, for example

```
4.5,3.5,U1
4.5,10.5,U2
4.5,6,U1
3.5,10.5,U2
3.5,10.5,U2
5,7,U1
7,6.5,U1
```

I need to classify this data to rows(matrix), where 1,2 row etc is data, last one is class. So I started with this code:

```
reader = csv.reader(open('test.data', 'r'))
result = []
for row in reader:
    result.append(row)
print result
```

output:

```
[['4.5', '3.5', 'U1'], ['4.5', '10.5', 'U2'], ['4.5', '6', 'U1'], ['3.5', '10.5', 'U2'], ['3.5', '10.5', 'U2'], ['5', '7', 'U1'], ['7', '6.5', 'U1']]
```

This all work ok, but now I need from this data make matrix classification. In this case I want to make matrix:

```
test data=[data1, data2,.....,class name1]
test data2=[data1, data2,.....,class name2]...
```

I need this "matrix"**(test data,test data2)**, because I will then choose from every **test data** just **2/3** data which will be named "**choosen**", other 1/3 data must stay in test data,....

So what I need as output:

```
choosen=[data,data,......class name1]         # 2/3 from every **test.data**
test data=[data1, data2,.....,class name1]    # other 1/3 from test data
test data2=[data1, data2,.....,class name1]   # other 1/3 from test data 2
```

> .
>
> . . . .

.

Many thanks for help

---

**EDIT2:**

If I use your code I get:

```
{
    'U1': [
              ['4.5','3.5'],
              ['4.5','6'],
              ['5','7'],
              ['7','6.5']
          ],
    'U2': [
              ['4.5','10.5'],
              ['3.5','10.5'],
              ['3.5','10.5']
          ]
}
```

But I don't have everytime this data:

```
4.5,3.5,U1
4.5,10.5,U2
4.5,6,U1
3.5,10.5,U2
3.5,10.5,U2
5,7,U1
7,6.5,U1
```

I have also:

```
4.5,3.5,4.5,10.5, U1
3.5,10.5,3.5,10.5,U2
4.5,12.5,3.5,12.5,U2
```

...... 
(so I don't know that class is on second row as you write on your code), but I know that last row is CLASS

So how can I change your code:

```
reader = csv.reader(open('test.data', 'r'))
result = {}
for row in reader:
    uclass=row[2]                      #-------> must be last row not second !!!!
    if result.has_key(uclass):
        result[uclass].append([row[0],row[1]])   #---->not just 2 row's, on other data I have for example 5 rows..
    else:
        result[uclass]=[[row[0],row[1]]]        #---->not just 2 row's, on other data I have for example 5 rows..
print repr(result)
```

Comment: To me it's really not clear what you are trying to do. Can you provide an explanation of the second part of the question using the data shown as example in the first? What would be the result you are looking for given the input data `4.5,3.5,U1...` ?

Comment: FYI: pythonese for "last element in list" is someList[-1] and "all but the last element" may be expressed as someList[0:-1].  This will works for strings as well: `"abcde"[0:-1]="abcd"` and `"abcde"[-1]="e"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** *Original code snippet modified to handle N-column input (last is class). This requirement was mentioned by the OP in a later reply.*

```
reader = csv.reader(open('test.data', 'r'))
result = {}
for row in reader:
    uclass=row[-1]
    if result.has_key(uclass):
        result[uclass].append(row[0:-1])
    else:
        result[uclass]=row[0:-1]
print repr(result)
```

*I'm still not completely sure about the second half of your problem.*
Something is missing in how you explained it perhaps.

If I understand this correctly you want a different list for each class?

If this is the case a dictionary should do what you want:

```
reader = csv.reader(open('test.data', 'r'))
result = {}
for row in reader:
    uclass=row[2]
    if result.has_key(uclass):
        result[uclass].append([row[0],row[1]])
    else:
        result[uclass]=[[row[0],row[1]]]
print repr(result)
```

result will look like:

```
{
    'U1': [
              ['4.5','3.5'],
              ['4.5','6'],
              ['5','7'],
              ['7','6.5']
          ],
    'U2': [
              ['4.5','10.5'],
              ['3.5','10.5'],
              ['3.5','10.5']
          ]
}
```

For the data skipping you can use the list slice skip option available in newer Pythons:

```
someList[<start>:<end>:<skip>]
```

so on a list like:

```
someList=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

using skip sliceing such as:

```
someList[0:10:2]
```

gives:

```
[0,2,4,6,8]
```

Comment: Yes, but I have various data, so not just 3 rows, where 1 and 2 is data and third one class. But everytime last row is class, and other one rows are data...;    Can you please change your code?

Comment: No you don't understand me; Please look at my first post. thanks

Comment: I have edited the first part of the code to handle N-column input as you elaborated in a comment.  I'm still fuzzy on the second half of your problem.  This data looks to me like groups of N-vectors (grouped by class) and you mention you want to make a matrix out of them.  You have to say what you mean more clearly by matrix.  It has several meanings across different problem domains (eg: such as in linear algerbra).